# Format datas from array to Json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv, format

In order to send data to an AJAX request, I need to send datas formated like that the code below.

```
{
    "columns": [
        [ "Name" ],
        [ "Position" ],
        [ "Office" ],
        [ "Extn." ],
        [ "Start date" ],
        [ "Salary" ]
    ],
    "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320800"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$170750"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The request works if I put this code into a .txt, but the aim of my code is to use datas from CSV file.. that's why I use this file.php :

```
<?php

//import csv file
if(!empty($_FILES['csv_file']['name']))
{
$file_data = fopen($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
  $csv = fgetcsv($file_data);
  //get header column  of csv file : 1rst line
  $heads = explode(';', $csv[0]);
    foreach ($heads as $head) {
     $json['columns'][] = [$head];
  }
//get  rows of csv file
 fgetcsv($file_data);
 while($row = fgetcsv($file_data))
 {
  $json['data'][] = array(
   $row[0],
   $row[1],
   $row[2],
   $row[3],
   $row[4],
   $row[5],
   $row[6],
   $row[7],
   $row[8],
   $row[9],
   $row[10],
  );
 }
echo json_encode($json);
 ?>
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

EDIT: 
and this is the file.csv (source of datas)

```
Name,Position,Office,Extn.,Start date,Salary
Tiger NixonSystem Architect,,Edinburgh,5421,25/04/2011,$320800
Garrett Winters,Accountant,Tokyo,8422,25/07/2011,$170750
```

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong no, because a) we can't see your CSV data, and b) you haven't told us what happens when you run the code.

Comment: show us the sample value of `var_export($json);` put it before `echo json_encode($json);` and add some of it's output into your question

Comment: `$320,800` and `$170,750` will be treated as two separate fields, because of the commas. If you want them to be a single field then, as per the standard feature of CSV, you have to surround the field with double quote marks e.g. `"$170,750"`. I don't know if that's your only problem, because you still haven't actually described what problem you're experiencing.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for helps.
I've edit again the CSV file, since this sample was not real: I don't use any ',' in my real source, that's why I've deleted these.
About "what's happen when I run the code" => since I use this code with an ajax request, there is not any error msg (even into the consol): but the ajax request doesn't success.

About var_export: I've just tried, but I'm not able to neither undestand the aim of this function, nor to undesrtand how to use it .

Comment: Also it's unclear what `$heads = explode(';', $csv[0]);` is intended to achieve, seeing as `;` does not exist anywhere in your header row.

Comment: The point of var_export is as a debugging tool, to see the current contents of the variable at the time when you run the command. You can look it up in the PHP manual in 2 seconds if you don't understand what it does! https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Comment: about describing my problem: the datas are not formated well (as the .txt) and that's why my ajax request is not able to read it. I'm not sure if the prob is the format, or an error into the method I used to build $json, but Ajax request respond nothing

Comment: _"there is not any error msg (even into the consol):"_ ...you can use your browser's Network tool to see what response the request actually gave (both status code, and response content). You can also enable error logging in PHP to get any server-side errors saved to a file on the server. There is no need to fly blind here!

Comment: ';' is contained into the array $csv[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code. Please try it. It's working.

I have remove header `foreach`. It's not required. Also, remove one to one array assign code in 2ed loop and add `$json['data'][] = explode(';', $row[0]);`code.

Here is the modified code.

```
<?php
//import csv file
if (!empty($_FILES['csv_file']['name'])) {
    $file_data = fopen($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    $csv = fgetcsv($file_data);

    //get header column  of csv file : 1rst line
    $json['columns'] = $csv;

    //get rows of csv file
    while ($row = fgetcsv($file_data)) {
        $json['data'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

**=> Output**

Array:

```
Array
(
    [columns] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name
            [1] => Position
            [2] => Office
            [3] => Extn.
            [4] => Start date
            [5] => Salary
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Tiger NixonSystem Architect
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => Edinburgh
                    [3] => 5421
                    [4] => 25/04/2011
                    [5] => $320800
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Garrett Winters
                    [1] => Accountant
                    [2] => Tokyo
                    [3] => 8422
                    [4] => 25/07/2011
                    [5] => $170750
                )

        )

)
```

JSON:

```
{"columns":["Name","Position","Office","Extn.","Start date","Salary"],"data":[["Tiger NixonSystem Architect","","Edinburgh","5421","25\/04\/2011","$320800"],["Garrett Winters","Accountant","Tokyo","8422","25\/07\/2011","$170750"]]}
```

Comment: this doesn't work:
Only 1 column can be called with this line: $json['data'][] = explode(';', $row[0]);
this line :  $json['columns'] = explode(';', $csv[0]); doesn't produce this format: "columns": [
        [ "Name" ],

Comment: thanks @Mukesh Singh, it almost works as expected, exept:
1) about columns part: I need [] around each header name (as show in the .txt output expected)
2) I meet another problem about caracter format: it seems some words are rewritten: "01\/04\/2020" for dates, \u00e9 instead of "é" ... etc.

Any idea?

Comment: Use `json_encode($json,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );` instead of `json_encode($json)`. If you are use ajax the also use `JSON.parse(data)` in javascript.